# Why does occlusion culling have a negative performance impact on Gear VR in Unity 5.4.03f?

Tags: unity, optimization, gearvr

I am making a GearVR game using Unity 5.4.03f and Oculus Utilities for Unity 5.

I have problem with Occlusion Culling. I've set appropriate objects as static and baked the data. The culling works correctly when I visualize it in the editor - I set a complex scene and hid it behind a big cube. The scene is not rendered when visualizing in the editor when the camera is behind the cube.

When I deploy this scene to the device, Samsung Galaxy S6. The culling does work - when looking at the complex scene through the occluding cube, I have good a framerate, the scene is culled. Without the cube and occlusion culling, the FPS would be around 40, with the cube and OC, it is around 60.

The problem starts when I get past the cube with OC on - the FPS drop to 30, while without OC in the same spot they were around 55.

I tried looking online for solutions, but this is supposed to be an old bug that was fixed back in Unity 5.1.X.

Any ideas?